# Strange halo around letters in firefox

Tags: 12.04, firefox, display

Couple days ago I've started noticing strange halo around letters in Firefox 18.0. On the same monitor, when running Firefox on Windows, nothing happens. Other Ubuntu apps work as well.
I'm attaching a screenshot. Look closely at red text, as it happen mostly around red text.

How to correct this effect?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Do you have Font anti aliasing or hinting active?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed any Gmail or Google add-ons to your Firefox lately?

Here are some things you might want to do in order to narrow down the possible causes:

1. Start Firefox on Safe Mode https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode
2. Disable one by one your add-ons https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/disable-or-remove-add-ons
3. Unpin the tab and then re-pin it